# How do I wire a ceiling fan with a light kit?

Tags: ceiling, ceiling-fan

Ceiling has three wires: one white, one black, and one bare. Fan has four wires: one white, one black, one blue, and one green. How do I connect wires?

Answer (score 4):

The manual for your fan should outline instructions for this type of wiring setup, but generally this will hold true:

Black in box goes to blue & black in fan.

White in box goes to white in fan.

Connect all grounds together.

This will cause your switch on the wall to control both the fan motor and fan lights. You'll have to use your pull chains to control the two independently.

Comment: You could also pull another wire (if you have hard pipe) or a romex wire if it's allowed by code. Then you can get another switch and control lights & fan independent. Another option is that a lot of fans have remote controls that you can use to control the fan and light separately. The answer above would still apply in that case.